# Straming Raspberry camera to own Apache Server - Command not found

Tags: camera, raspicam, apache-httpd, streaming, ffmpeg

I am planning to implement a camera video stream from the Raspberry Pi to its own Apache server. I trying to solve this for a week now and i am pretty frustrated by now. I came across [this tutorial](https://www.nick-horne.com/2013/08/16/raspberry-pi-stream-webcam-to-apache-server/) and i thought my problem was finally solved. I don't think the original author would answere me if I wrote him, since this tutorial is really old. So maybe one of you can help me with the problem. I did every step that was mentioned and got to the last step where i had to start the stream with the command on the bottom of the tutorial. The problem is that when I type it in and hit `Enter`, I get the following Error: `-bash: ffmpeg: command not found`.
I really hope you can help me with that.

Comment: Welcome! If you get the error "command not found" then the linux command `whereis` is your best friend, try `whereis ffmpeg` to find out if this command is available. But this is not RPi specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install ffmpeg on your system:

`sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`

However I suggest you have a look at the 'motion' package which will do this and a lot more: https://motion-project.github.io/

Comment: Thank you for your answere. Installing ffmpeg solved the problem. But now i face the next problem: When i try to view the stream in my browser it just shows a black image. The camera is working fine(I made a test photo).

Comment: Try using a different browser.  I've noticed firefox works better for me.  Don't forget to mark this answer as accepted (solved).